# Magento 2 - Customer Notifications don't disappear?

Tags: magento2, customer

I'm running 2.0.7 production and I have a problem where by any notifications to customers remain on the site even when navigating to another page. For example adding to cart or adding an email to newsletter subscription generates the success message however the reappear on every page afterwards?

Anyone had this and know how to stop it?

Comment: did you find out what the issue is?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Magento 2: Customer related notifications do not disappear even after refreshing the page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/198589/magento-2-customer-related-notifications-do-not-disappear-even-after-refreshing)

Answer (score 2):

For me this seemed to be coming from having the cache disabled. I enabled all the caches and the issue went away.